# Where does Opera Mini save its "Saved pages"?

Tags: opera-mini

When you save a web page in Opera Mini, it must be saved somewhere.

I want to know where can I find these pages, specific path or anything?

Comment: Can you post an app screenshot of this "saved pages" feature you're talking about, for reference?

Answer (score 0):

Users of Opera mini can Save web pages for later viewing, by Tapping the + button on the search bar to save a page.

Once pages is Saved, one can actually access the Saved pages from Opera mini browser app itself.

Once you Save web pages for offline viewing, these Saved pages are added to a Speed Dial group named **Saved pages**

This can be accessed by clicking on the Saved pages tab as shown in screen shot below.

[image]

Comment: I think OP asked about the physical location (i.e. "specific path") of the saved pages, but I might be wrong.

Comment: AndrewT.  - Is right, The OP asked about the path.

Comment: @AndrewT. The op asked like this : "I want to know where can I find these pages, specific path or anything" So basically, OP wants to find these pages. my Post should help to address that.